# selecting all information from 4 tables combining them in one

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following tables:

Table: **products**

```
product_id | name
------------------------------
1          | apple iphone 7
2          | samsung galaxy s8
```

Table: **attribute_categories**

```
attribute_category_id | name
------------------------------------------
1                     | Fysical properties
2                     | Color
```

Table: **attributes**

```
attribute_id | attribute_category_id | name
---------------------------------------------
1            | 1                     | width
2            | 1                     | height
3            | 1                     | Weight
4            | 2                     | Color
```

Table: **attribute_values**

```
attribute_value_id | product_id | attribute_id | value
---------------------------------------------------------
1                  | 1          | 1            | 8 cm
2                  | 1          | 2            | 12 cm
3                  | 1          | 3            | 0,125 kg
4                  | 1          | 4            | blue
5                  | 2          | 1            | 8 cm
6                  | 2          | 2            | 10 cm
7                  | 2          | 3            | 0,400 kg
8                  | 2          | 4            | red
```

First of all, I want to select all the information in one query (if possible), and represent it like this:

```
Array(
    [product_id] => 1
    [name] => apple iphone 7
    [attributes] => Array(
         [0] => Array(
             [name] => Fysical properties
             [attributes] => Array(
                 [0] => Array(
                     [name] => width
                     [value] => 8 cm
                 )
                 [1] => Array(
                     [name] => height
                     [value] => 12 cm
                 )
                 [2] => Array(
                     [name] => weight
                     [value] => 0,125 kg
                 )
             )
         [1] => Array(
             [name] => Color
             [attributes] => Array(
                 [0] => Array(
                     [name] => color
                     [value] => blue
                 )
             )
```

Currently, I'm using 3 queries, but I think one query will work.

First, I'm selecting all the attributes from the database.

Second, I create some SQL-code in PHP to put all the attributes in the SQL-code.

Third, I select all the attribute_categories from the database.

Fourth, I select all the product information + attribute_values from the database.

My code:

```
foreach($attributes as $attribute){
    // creating some SQL-code
    $c .= "MAX(IF(a.name = '".$attribute['name']."', fa.value, NULL)) as '".$attribute['name']."',";
};


$q =    "SELECT p.product_id AS product_id,
                p.name AS product_name,
                {$c}
                a.attribute_category_id AS category_id
        FROM products p 
            LEFT JOIN attribute_values fa ON p.product_id = fa.product_id
            LEFT JOIN attributes a ON fa.attribute_id = a.attribute_id
        GROUP BY p.product_id";
```

This works, but it's a LOT of code to create the array I described before. And I think there is a simpler way to do this. Can anyone give me an example/hint/whatsoever?

Comment: Which DB interface are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: I mean PDO or mysqli or some third party library?

Comment: Oh ok I'm sorry. I'm using MySQLi with prepared statements.

Comment: And you want attribute-value-pairs for one specific product grouped by categories?

Comment: yes, of it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have fetched the product info into an array

```
$product = ['product_id' => 1, 'name' => 'apple iphone 7'];
```

Fetch all related attributes:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
    select
        a.name as attr_name,
        v.value,
        c.attribute_category_id as cat_id,
        c.name as cat_name
    from attribute_values v
    join attributes a using(attribute_id)
    join attribute_categories c using(attribute_category_id)
    where v.product_id = ?
");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $product['product_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Create the array as you need while fetching the rows:

```
$attributes = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if (!array_key_exists($row['cat_id'], $attributes)) {
        // init categorie
        $attributes[$row['cat_id']] = [
            'name'       => $row['cat_name'],
            'attributes' => []
        ];
    }
    $attributes[$row['cat_id']]['attributes'][] = [
        'name'  => $row['attr_name'],
        'value' => $row['value']
    ];
}
```

Assign the attributes to the product array:

```
$product['attributes'] = $attributes;
```

The `$product['attributes']` will be indexed by the categries id. But it shouldn't matter.